# LaTeX conflict between biblatex and draftmark?

Tags: biblatex

I need to use `biblatex` for a draft of a report. I'd like to use `draftmark` to create a water mark as well. However, the document fails to compile even with just the `usepackage` statements. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letter]{report}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{draftmark}

\begin{document}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{document}
```

And I get the following error:

```
\file \blx@list@req@stat \advance \lrq@indent \m@ne \xappto \lrq@hook@data \ETC
Latex Error: ./untitled.tex:14 Paragraph ended before \ettl@forloop was complete.

Latex Error: ./untitled.tex:14 Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex: \pdfmatch: repetition-operator operand invalid

! Emergency stop.

! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Any idea what's going on here or if there's a work around?

**EDIT**

Additionally, I would like to add a draft watermark to the bottom of the page, in the footer area (so that it's easier to others to read).

[I am running pdfTeX (TeX Live 2012) through TextMate on Mac OS X]

Comment: I fear, you are out of luck. `draftmark` uses `etextools` package whereas `biblatex` uses `etoolbox` -- package -- those two packages do not behave well in the same setup.

Comment: Hi @ChristianHupfer, that is what I had feared (and some initial Google sleuthing was leading me to believe). Is there an alternative draftmark type toolbox that can be used instead? I suppose `draftwatermark`  could be used but I like to use custom watermarks (hence using `draftmark` to begin with)

Comment: Perhaps my little 'hack' is a solution for you?

Comment: I should have been more specific in my question: the reason I was using `draftmark` was because I need to put the watermark along the bottom of the page, in the footer area with smaller font. Can your hack handle that?

Comment: Well, you asked for the incompatibility, now you're editing your question away ;-) I'll try

Comment: I was hoping it wouldn't be compatibility ;) I will edit my question accordingly.

Comment: See the update please. I hope you will be able to compile with TeXlive 2012 (which is really outdated!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `draftmark` uses `etextools` and `biblatex` applies macros from `etoolbox`, the usage of both packages in the same document is hopeless -- they do not match.

A similar watermark for content can be achieved with Gonzalo Medina's `background` package, which is quite easy to configure, however, there's no `draft` feature. Please note, that the package usage requires two compilation runs to get the underlying `tikz` anchors correct, but this is no issue, since most documents need two runs.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{biblatex}


\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\backgroundsetup{contents=DRAFT,color=blue}

\begin{document}
  \blindtext[5]
\end{document}
```

**Edit** A small 'hack' to use the `draft` option of the `report.cls`

```
\documentclass[11pt,draft]{report}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\newif\ifdraftmode  % Define the `\ifdraftmode` conditional
\draftmodefalse     % Set it to false --> not the draft mode

\DeclareOption{draft}{\draftmodetrue\setlength\overfullrule{5pt}} % set draft mode to true if specified
\ProcessOptions*  % Reprocess options

\ifdraftmode                   % Check for draftmode
\usepackage{background}        % Within the check, because the package automatically sets a pink coloured 'Draft' in the background
\backgroundsetup{angle=0,scale=3,placement=bottom,vshift=0.5cm,contents=DRAFT,color=blue} 
\fi


\begin{document}
\blindtext[5]
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]